# Invoke async method on button click Flutter

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, future

I have for example this future function:

```
Future<void> sayHello() async {
   await service.sayHello();
}
```

And I want to invoke it on button click

```
ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () => sayHello(),
    child: const Text("Click"),
)
```

My question is, should onPressed be async when I want to invoke future function on clicked? Could it be async anyway?

Comment: onPressed: () async => sayHello(),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to call your function like this:

```
ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () => sayHello(),
    child: const Text("Click"),
)
```

no you don't need to set `async` for onPressed, but if you want to call it like this:

```
ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () async{
      var result = await sayHello()
    },
    child: const Text("Click"),
)
```

you need call `async`, because you need to `await` for it.

Answer (score 1):

button click

```
 ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () async => sayHello(),
                    child: const Text("Click"),
                  ),
```

future function:

```
Future<void> sayHello() async {
   await service.sayHello();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Suchin Kumawat said you can you both cases.

Whenevever you're about to use `await` operator in function body you should define it as `async`. Refer to [Asynchronous programming](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await). More specially look at [Working with futures: async and await](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await#working-with-futures-async-and-await) for it covers this subject.

## But

Pay attention that `onPressed` will be called rather *synchronously* by Flutter. So, if your on `onPressed` body supposed to be a long and heavy *consider not using `await`* in it. Otherwise you'll experience lags and frozen frames in your UI.

Instead you can call an `async` function, but don't wait for its `Future` object. Just let Flutter to schedule it in between the UI tasks.

For example you can do following:

```dart
onPressed: () => Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 0), () {
  // Do heavy staff here
});
```

The result of `Future.delayed(/*with 0 delay*/)` will be.. a `Future` object. And this is a task to Flutter which will be scheduled in nearest possible future. So current UI task will be all cool.